# Use virtual pageviews for Facebook Pixel code

Tags: facebook, analytics, web-analytics, virtual-path, facebook-pixel

I want to use facebook pixel code for remarketing purposes and I am intend to remarket to only who did not complete it to thank you page.

However, in the booking engine pages, page url is all same, from the first page to thank you page.

Is there a way to set a virtual pageview (virtual page url) for the facebook pixel code (just like we do in Google Analytics), so I could segment the right audience?

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, this isn't an answer - did you find one @cool_kid? I have scoured the interwebs for quite some time now and can find anything yet that works. My scenario is that there is a guid in the querystring and FB is picking that up, and we don't want it to. Adding a comment so perhaps this will get bumped and someone who knows might reply.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to send a page view after page load, then just simply use the `send()` function on whatever trigger it is that you want, in your case it's moving between different slides in a SPA.

```
ga('send', 'pageview', [page], [fieldsObject]);
```